# {gtsummary} R package -- Problem passing arguments from `add_difference()` to custom function

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm trying to use a custom function for testing in a `tbl_summary |> add_difference()` call.

Basically, whatever I pass the function via the `test.arg` argument in `add_difference` doesn't get to the called function. I made a simplified version of my code below--I'm pretty sure it's far from optimized and probably full of other bugs I can't see because I'm stuck at the call!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

# Most args are necessary for any function to be compatible with
# add_difference()
testMe <- function(data,
                   variable,
                   by,
                   group = NULL,
                   type = NULL,
                   conf.level = 0.95,
                   adj.vars = NULL,
                   # test_name is the one I got problems with
                   test_name = NULL,
                   ci_type = 0.95,
                   continuous_variable = NULL,
                   na.rm,
                   ...) {
    
    # Turn strings into actual symbol for valiables
    variable <- ensym(variable)
    by <- ensym(by)
    
    # Use functions from infer to make statistical computations
    estimate <- data |> specify(expr(!!variable ~ !!by)) |> 
        calculate(stat = test_name, na.rm = na.rm)
    
    booted <- data |> 
        specify(expr(!!variable ~ !!by)) |> 
        generate(reps = 1000, type = "bootstrap") |> 
        calculate(stat = test_name, na.rm = na.rm)
    
    result_df <- get_confidence_interval(booted,
                                         estimate,
                                         type = "bias-corrected",
                                         point_estimate = estimate) |> 
        rename(conf.low = lower_ci,
               conf.high = upper_ci)
    
    # returns a df with column names as specified in gtsummary docs
    return(result_df)
}
```

This is the `gtsummary` code:

```
# Turn the group factor into character (per add_difference()) and reduce
# groups to 2.
pdata <- PlantGrowth |> filter((group == "trt1") | (group == "trt2")) |> 
    mutate(group = as.character(group))

table <- data |> 
    tbl_summary(
        by = group,
        statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{median} ({p25}—{p75})"),
    ) |> 
    add_difference(
        test = list(weight ~ "testMe"),
        # Here we pass a string containing the name of the estimate which
        # the infer functions will need.
        test.args = weight ~ list(test_name = "diff in medians")

        # The following selection, which I've seen in documentation and on the
        # Internet, doesn't work for me.
        # test.args = all_tests("testMe) ~ list(test_name = "diff in medians")

    )
```

In my attempts, the testMe function is called but its `test_name` argument is always `NULL` (i.e. default); all subsequent errors are due to its being blank, and if I set a sensible default, the function always returns the subsequent result.

When I change `testMe` not to have a default `test_name`, I get an "argument missing" error. In other words, `test.args` isn't working for me…

Am I getting something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Marco, I need to look into the details more, but I am not at a computer to do so. I don't think that `all_tests()` or `test.args=` are compatible with custom functions. I've made a note for myself to look the details up and make the documentation 100% clear on this.

Comment: Hi Daniel, did you have the chance to take a look at this issue?

Comment: I haven't. But you can subscribe to this GitHub Issue if you'd like to follow along. https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/1284